# Filter the required lines using bash

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file named "check", which contains the following,

```
calendar: A
Des: bad
04/12/2009 00:00
09/11/2010 00:00
calendar: B
Des: bad
04/09/2013 00:00
08/08/2013 00:00
calendar: B1
Des: bad
04/03/2014 00:00
04/02/2014 00:00
calendar: C
Des: bad
04/05/2009 00:00
09/11/2010 00:00
```

I have to filter only the calendar: B* and the corresponding des and dates and place it in a separate file using bash scripting
the above given is an example and the actual file will contain more than 200 lines. I tried

```
 awk '/calendar: B/{print}' check
```

as the command gives the tag and not the details below to it. I need to have an command which gives the details too

Comment: something like this? grep "calendar: B" -A3 file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk command.

```
awk '/^calendar/{p=0} /^calendar: B/{p=1} p' check
```

Comment: awk '/^calendar: B/{x=4}x-->0' check, it worked for the file given above, but the actual files does have many dates(not limited to two),

Comment: updated, try it again.

Comment: Amazing!!!Thanks much